# Wordpress create new <section> on site when a new page is added

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a single page wordpress theme. Whenever I add a new page, I want a new  to be added to my Single page theme. I'm currently using this code:

```
$pages = get_pages( array ( 'sort_order' => 'asc', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'depth' => 1));

        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {  
        $page_section = str_replace( " ", "", strtolower( $page->post_name ) );

        echo '<section id="' . $page_section . '" dataslug="' . $page_section . '"  ></section>';
        }
        ?>
```

What I want is for it to create a new  with  an ID and Dataslug that match the page name (which is also the label on the link in the Menu). For example, say I insert a page called about, The menu item will read "about" and this code will be added to the page

```
<section id="about" dataslug="about"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, there is no such thing as "dataslug", changed it to "data-slug" and it worked perfectly. Really stupid mistake.

I guess most people don't use the  tag, but if anyone wants to know you could easily replace it with a  and give it a 'scrollto' class using the scrollto jquery plugin. Just a thought.